# What specifies the retry count of ACK during TCP connection establishment?

Tags: tcp

In the following TCP connection establishment diagram, [tcp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) says that `tcp_syn_retries` specifies the retry count for `SYN` and `tcp_synack_retries` specifies the retry count of for `SYN+ACK`. There is no something like `tcp_ack_retries` to specify the retry count for `ACK`.

```
side-a        side-b
       SYN
      ------->
       SYN+ACK
      <-------
       ACK
      ------->
```

But there are `tcp_retries1` and `tcp_retries2`. The description for `tcp_retries1` says:

> The number of times TCP will attempt to retransmit a packet on an established connection normally.

And after `side-a` receives `SYN+ACK`, the connection for sending data to side-b is established. So I think that `tcp_retries1` and `tcp_retries2` specifies the retry count of `ACK`. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing an understanding of what ACK is.
 ACK is an acknowledgement that some data was received. There is no response expected to an ACK. And, if no response is expected it is not known if the ACK was delivered or not, i.e. if a redelivery is needed or not.
Instead, if an ACK is lost the peer will resend the data which was not yet acknowledged in the assumption that either the original data was lost or that the ACK was lost. And, this will result in another ACK sent back to the peer.

Comment: So ACK will not be retried by side-a. Consequently, there is no such a retry count option. Right?

Comment: @JingguoYao: exactly